# Input string not in a correct format in encoder and decoder (C#)

Tags: c#, encoder

I've been developing a program in C# that encodes characters into their values (e.g, A: 65). However, I'm getting a debug error in the decoding event that states that the input string was not in a correct format. Will somebody try to help me please? Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Decode_Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = encoderBox.Text;
            decoderBox.Text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
            {
                int code = message[i];
                decoderBox.Text += String.Format("{0} ", code);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] messageCodes = decoderBox.Text.Split(' ');
            int[] codes = new int[messageCodes.Length];
            char[] letters = new char[codes.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < codes.Length; i++)
            {
                codes[i] = int.Parse(messageCodes[i]);
                letters[i] = Convert.ToChar(codes[i]);
                encoderBox.Text = "";
                encoderBox.Text += letters[i];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get the error, look at the `messageCodes` current value, it's probably not a number (or at the line you get the error, but I very much suspect it's your `int.Parse`). As a side note : you're overwriting `encoderBox` value each time, the final result will only be the last letter. As a bigger side note, `char`s are implicitly `int`s, so you can pretty much reduce all your code to `int[] codes = decoderBox.Text.Select(c => (int)c).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your input is `ABC`, after clicking on `button1`, your encoded text will be `"65 66 67 "`. (Notice the *extra* space at the end of the string.)

So when you click on `button2`, you will get:

```
messageCodes[0]: "65"
messageCodes[1]: "66"
messageCodes[2]: "67"
messageCodes[3]: ""    // <-- An extra empty string... Bad!
```

And when you do the `int.Parse` for the last item (the empty string), it will fail.

What you need to do is to trim the text before splitting it, as in:

```
string[] messageCodes = decoderBox.Text.Trim().Split(' ');
```

Also, as an aside, you should move the `encoderBox.Text = "";` out of the `for` loop in order for it to work properly, as in:

```
encoderBox.Text = "";

for (int i = 0; i < codes.Length; i++)
{
    codes[i] = int.Parse(messageCodes[i]);
    letters[i] = Convert.ToChar(codes[i]);
    encoderBox.Text += letters[i];
}
```